# Why can't I open/view my OWN Task?

Tags: task-list

I have a Workflow that creates a Task and assigns it to me.

From my domain account I login, and click on the Task.

I get a permissions error ???

I do NOT get this error when I login as the System Account.

My user domain account has full perms on the site collection.

Any help?

[image]

---

Update

This is for a SharePoint Designer workflow. It is just a customized Approval workflow (OOB).

Using SPDesigner I go to All Files -> Workflows -> TFS Setup (my workflow in question) and I see an XSN for the Task that is spawned by the workflow is CHECKED OUT to System Account.  I tried to Check in and get an error (below). I tried to Undo Checkout and that won't work either.  I deleted it and republished workflow, it recreated the form, but again, leaves it Checked Out with no option to CheckIn or Undo Checkout.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's wrong. What kind of workflow is it (SPDesigner vs VisualStudio)? It looks like you're using an InfoPath form for your tasks, or workflow forms? If this is the case, is your user account able to access other IP forms? If this is not the case, I'm not sure why the error is stating a form template, xsn, file causes the issue. I'm hoping it's a IP Form Services related permission issue.

Comment: @April D., does your workflow reference any other list?

Comment: yes it does.  I was able to recover one of these by manually editing all fields in the workflow.  but that workaround isn't working on another one.

Comment: Your workflow title is TFS Setup.  Is the workflow interacting with Team Foundation Server?  Do you have other similar workflows that do work?  Is this a workflow that was working and broke or is it new and you have never gotten it to work?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a not that common but it does happen sometimes kind of issue.

Simply put **you have an error in your infopath form.**

Check the rules on the form for errors and/or any code. If you don't see anything then look in the ULS log at that correlation ID and report back the results if you can't solve it instantly from that error.

Comment: I have made NO edits to the InfoPath form(s) that this occurs on. I even delete them and have them recreated when the workflow republishes.

Comment: here's the log error:  7a4b74ae-963b-472c-b9ee-650a11ada005 - Cannot open file "Workflows/Release Tracking Master Workflow/Release Tracking Master Workflow.xsn".

Comment: also: The XSN is null after attempting to get it from SiteAndWebCache. The XSN is null and its not a cross server issue. Most likely a permission issue

Comment: I would say the form is missing a required field or something like that. This would make it look like it is fine and without issue but however it won't work. *thought* it might be the title field, check the content type and remove required fields, it may tell you it can't do it but it will.

Comment: The problem is, there hasn't been any editing of that form. or any of them. and when they are destroyed and recreated by the publishing process, they are 'recreated with the same bug/problem'. so I am left with no recovery still.